# fit to screen in chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

In Opera if I zoom pages I can still have the page fit to screen so no scroll bars appear. How to do that in Chrome?

Comment: Did you mean 'zoom to fit width and height'? 
'How to do that?' Did you mean by a function in chrome or by a chrome extension or by programming in google-chrome-extension?

Comment: i have a tiny screen and when i zoom a webpage, i get scrollbars esp horizontal , in chrome.....like mobile , text does not auto fits to screen. If u do same on Opera, no matter how many levels you zoom , you wont get any horizontal scrollbar on any webpage. 

So is there any extension for chrome to do same ?

Comment: Ok, so, you need an extension.

Answer (score 0):

There a few Chrome extensions than can add that functionality. Here are some of them:

Fit to width:
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/fit-to-width/dfdmbpdbpocelpgahddghhkomnefchkl?hl=en

iZoom:
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/izoom/iheccogfcpjfjbnlohnlgdljaefpgaoi

Zoomy:
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/zoomy/jgfonhdeiaaflpgphemdgfkjimojblie

EZ Zoom:
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ez-zoom/pgjddfakmeeljhjhnhgakblggcfkmima

Chrome extensions are little additions to browser developed independently by individual external developers. They can be installed directly in browser. And some also have their own settings which you can modify to suit your exact requirements. Go to 'Settings -> More Tools -> Extensions' for installing, uninstalling or fine-tuning each extension individually.